# Explanation about bottom overflowed message

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand the following Scaffold:

```
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          PostCrud().crearNuevoPostTest(_miId);
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<List<OtroUsuario>>(
              stream: otrosUsuariosBloc.todosOtrosUsuarios(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                if (index == 0) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {},
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 67,
                                            height: 67,
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                  image: AssetImage(
                                                      "assets/images/buscar_usuario.png"),
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  var otro_usuario = snapshot.data[index - 1];

                                  bool is_ambassador = false;
                                  is_ambassador = otro_usuario.is_ambassador;

                                  if (is_ambassador) {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      child: Stack(
                                        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                        overflow: Overflow.visible,
                                        children: [
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width: 65,
                                                height: 65,
                                                margin:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    border: Border.all(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      width: 3,
                                                    ),
                                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                                          otro_usuario
                                                              .profile_image),
                                                    )),
                                              ),
                                              Text(otro_usuario.username,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Colors.red)),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Positioned(
                                            left: 61,
                                            top: 52,
                                            child: Container(
                                                height: 22,
                                                width: 22,
                                                child: Image(
                                                    image: AssetImage(
                                                        "assets/images/home_ambassador.png"))),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 70,
                                            height: 70,
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  width: 3,
                                                ),
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                                      otro_usuario
                                                          .profile_image),
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            otro_usuario.username,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                    );
                                  }
                                }
                              }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.teal,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I should see a horizontal listview at the top of the screen and an empty container with a teal background, but I only see a teal screen with a bottom overflowed by 36 pixels message and a floating button.

Screenshots:

[image]

I would like to know why exactly 36 pixeles in all devices (iPhone 12, iPhone 7, Android, etc.) and why is the listview not shown.

Comment: Can you include an image that you like to archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,` of screen just for container and using Column as it's parent, But Others children is not getting any spaces. You can wrap  `body: Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`. And second problem appear on wrapping `ListView.builder` with `Expanded`. By wrapping with  `SizedBox(height:X,` solve the issue.

```
  SizedBox(
            height: 200, // depend on childrens size
            child: ListView.builder(..
```

By wrapping with `Expanded` is not working because the listView ancestor Column(after padding) size is not defined and column parents also coming from Column Widget. You can wrap with `SizedBox` with Column, and It will also solve the issue.

Here is the full Widget, and I've added comments on those parts. But I would prefer `CustomScrollView` in this case.

[image]

Hope you will get the snippet

```
return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          // PostCrud().crearNuevoPostTest(_miId);
        },
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            // StreamBuilder<List<OtroUsuario>>(
            //     stream: otrosUsuariosBloc.todosOtrosUsuarios(),
            //     builder: (context, snapshot) {
            //       if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

            // return
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
                // height: 200, // you can provide height here
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    /// ListView wi getting Infinite height and we cant use `Expanded while using [SingleChildScrollView]`
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 200, // depend on childrens size
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 44,

                          // snapshot.data.length + 1,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            // return Text("item $index");
                            if (index == 0) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        width: 67,
                                        height: 67,
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  "assets/images/buscar_usuario.png"),
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            } else {
                              // var otro_usuario = snapshot.data[index - 1];

                              bool is_ambassador = true;
                              is_ambassador = 1 < 2;
                              // otro_usuario.is_ambassador;

                              // return Text("On Else");
                              if (is_ambassador) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  child: Stack(
                                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                    overflow: Overflow.visible,
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 65,
                                            height: 65,
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  width: 3,
                                                ),
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                                    " otro_usuario.profile_image",
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "otro_usuario.username",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.red,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        left: 61,
                                        top: 52,
                                        child: Container(
                                            height: 22,
                                            width: 22,
                                            child: Image(
                                                image: AssetImage(
                                                    "assets/images/home_ambassador.png"))),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {},
                                );
                              } else {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        width: 70,
                                        height: 70,
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border.all(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              width: 3,
                                            ),
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              image: NetworkImage(
                                                  "   otro_usuario.profile_image"),
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        " otro_usuario.username",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {},
                                );
                              }
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // }
            ),

            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.teal,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: The result implementing your proposal is a white screen and the floating button

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, Add your Column inside SingleChildScrollView()

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
     children:[
     //Your Widgets
      ],
   ),
),
```

Comment: Which Column? The first just in the body tag?

Comment: And what about the 36 pixels?

Comment: In body tag Column  1st one

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this replace your column with `ListView`

```
ListView(
    shirkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    children: [
       // add your streambuilder()
       ]
     )
```

Comment: and the streambuilder?

Comment: same result, no changes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold can have a background

```
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: YourColor,
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          PostCrud().crearNuevoPostTest(_miId);
        },
      ),
   body: Column(
   children: [
     //Your Streambuilder an beyond,
    //try remove Container below,
    //if you want thing like widgets be scrollable wrap your column to 
    //SingleSchildScrollView
    ]
    )
);
```

Inside your streambuilder have a widget plus it also eat space which means it specify some part of the screen plus you put a Container below on the Column makes it overlap and you did was made a Container and call Mediaquery that get the screens size to full.